# Formulas that generate "too few" primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I am looking for examples of formulas $f: \mathbf{N} \rightarrow \mathbf{N}$ for which the number of conjectured primes $p \in \text{ Im}(f)$ is either finite or *less* than what naive heuristics would suggest.

Let $\pi_{f(n)}(N)$ denote the number of naturals $n \leq N$ such that $f(n)$ is prime.

For example, consider $f(n) = n^2 + 1$. It is conjectured that $\pi_{f(n)}(N) \sim \frac{N}{\log(N^2+1)} \sim \frac{N}{2\log(N)}$. This naive heuristic (which is based on the Prime Number Theorem) seems to agree with numerical testing. In other words, the distribution of primes in $\text{ Im}(f)$ seems to be "similar" to the distribution of primes in $\mathbf{N}$, with not too many additional divisibility constraints.

However, if we instead take $f(n) = 2^{2^n} + 1$, it is conjectured that $f(4)$ is the last such prime. In fact, $f(1), f(2), f(3)$, and $f(4)$ are believed to be the only primes of this form. Heuristics about primes in general likely fail in this case, suggesting that there are significant additional divisibility constraints. I am looking for more examples like this one.

For more careful heuristics about these primes, see Conway and Boklan's paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01371.pdf.

**Correction:** Of course, if there is an obvious reason why a formula is prime for finitely many values of $n$ like $f(n) = n^2 - 1 = (n-1)(n+1)$, then I don't really care about it.

Comment: The restriction in the case of the Fermat numbers does not matter much because the numbers are so huge that the probability of them to be prime is still extremely small. I read somewhere that a careful analysis predicts a chance of 1 to a billion that there is another Fermat-prime.

Comment: The smallest candidate is $F_{33}$

Comment: That's right, the paper I linked is precisely that analysis.